# Selecting one checkbox in loop-generated checkboxes from checkboxlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database, checkbox

Sorry for my poor english.

On my ASP.NET website, I'm importing a softwares list from a SQL table, looking like this, but in reality much longer :

```
Microsoft Application Error Reporting<br><br />Microsoft Application Error Reporting<br><br />Microsoft Office Professional Plus2010<br><br />Microsoft Office OneNote MUI (English) 2010<br><br/>Microsoft Office InfoPath MUI (English) 2010<br><br />Microsoft Office Access MUI (English) 2010<br><br />Microsoft Office Shared Setup Metadata MUI (English) 2010<br><br />
```

To create the checkbox, I did it this way :

```
  int i = 1;
            CheckBoxList1.Items.Clear();
            foreach (char c in Resultat)
            {
                string value = ""+i;
                if (c == '/')
                {
                    CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(value);
                    i++;
                }
            }
```

And it looks like this :

[ScreenWebsite](http://www.noelshack.com/2012-22-1338536532-PartSiteWebV3.png)
( Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to directly post the picture )

What I'd like to do now is performing a specific command for each checkbox I... check.
I don't know how to select a specific checkbox as my checkboxes have no ID.

Thanks a lot for you help, and sorry again for my english.

Comment: _"What I'd like to do now is performing a specific command for each checkbox... i check"_ On client- or on serverside? If the latter, why cant you use the `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedValue` to determine the command to perform?

Comment: listbox1.items[index].IsChecked = true; try this

Comment: have you set the autopostback property to true of checkedlistbox item

Comment: Thanks for your answers. 
Tim : I tried using SelectedValue but for an unknown reason it didn't work, maybe I'm using it in a wrong way :/

Jodha : Thanks for it, but there is no IsChecked method, only "Equals", "GetHashCode", "GetType" and "ToString". :/

Edit : Oh crap I didn't, I'm gonna do it now.

Comment: @Pierre Pellegrino Milza Do you want to do get selected checkbox id?

Comment: stay_hungry : Yeah, this is exactly what I'd like to do ! But my checkboxes don't have an ID since I creating them with "CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(value);", am I right ? :x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
      { 
   foreach var item in CheckBoxList1.Items
    {
       if(item.Selected)
       {
         string value = item.Text;
         'DO SOMETHING
       }
    }
}
```

You can this also:

```
void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
      {

         for (int i=0; i<checkboxlist1.Items.Count; i++)
         {

            if (checkboxlist1.Items[i].Selected)
            {

               string value = checkboxlist1.Items[i].Text;

            }

         }

      }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, should I replace "item" with something else ? Because there's no "Selected" property for "item" :/
Sorry I'm more or less a beginner in c# :/

Comment: @PierrePellegrinoMilza I have updated my answer with new option. Both result the same functionality.

Comment: `foreach var item in CheckBoxList1.Items` this you can replace with `foreach ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items`, is you are not using C# 3.0.

Comment: I still can't display text ( I tried in a textbox ) but I'm working on it, thanks a LOT for the second code, very understandable and I'm sure it will be very useful. Thanks again for it, I'll try now to display the CheckBox text in my textbox. :)