# Selected checkbox is not recognized as such

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, checkboxlist

I've got a checkboxlist with a variable amount of checkboxes, and I'm doing something like it :

```
protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; j++)
        {
            //LabelTest.Text = "Something"; It works here
            if (CheckBoxList1.Items[j].Selected)
            {
                //LabelTest.Text = "Something 2"; It doesn't work here
                TextBoxTest.Text = CheckBoxList1.Items[j].Text;
                LabelTest.Text = CheckBoxList1.Items[j].Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I check a box, the "Something" is displaying on my page, but the rest isn't.
I tried to write my "if" like it too :

```
if (!CheckBoxList1.Items[j].Selected)
```

And doing like so, when I check a box, my TextBoxTest displays "106", which is the total number of checkboxes I have, but not the number of the checked box.

My CheckBoxList1 has a true autopostback.

Comment: can u show the code where u populate the checkboxlist

Comment: Of course, I asked another question earlier and everything ( I think ) is on it :) 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846445/selecting-one-checkbox-in-loop-generated-checkboxes-from-checkboxlist

Comment: When are you populating your checkboxes? If you're recreating them on each `Page_Load` you could be overriding the fact that you've checked one.

Comment: Oh crap ! Yep I'm recreating them on each Page_Load like you said ! Thanks for the tip i'm gonna check it out right now ! Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the way you add items to your CheckBoxList. You provided the code for that in another topic. What you should do is to enclose that code inside this:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    ... your code to add items to the CheckBoxList
}
```

Otherwise, you recreate the list on every postback with the default values of false for the Selected property.

Comment: Thank you SO much ! You got it ! I now get the actual number of the checked box. Thank you man, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

For checkboxes you should use the property `Checked` and not `Selected`:

```
 if (CheckBoxList1.Items[j].Checked)
```

But I can't test this right now.

Comment: I tried so, but I've got a "blah blah doesn't not contain a definition for "Checked" " so I changed to "Selected" :/

Comment: @PierrePellegrinoMilza: How can it be that your checkbox does not have a Checked property. Look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.aspx

Comment: What is the fully qualified type of the CheckBoxList?

Comment: @PierrePellegrinoMilza: Let us assume it is not there, then do a casting `((CheckBox)CheckBoxList1.Items[j]).Checked`

Comment: @PierrePellegrinoMilza: is it really a checkbox list control?

Comment: I just found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist) that: The CheckBoxList control provides a multi selection check box group that can be dynamically generated with data binding. It contains an Items collection with members corresponding to individual items in the list. To determine which items are checked, iterate through the collection and test the Selected property of each item in the list.

Comment: Nikhil Agrawal : Yeah it sounded weird to me too, especially when I saw the MSDN CheckBox Class, but I don't know, it won't let me use a Checked property.. :(

Franky : Erm, I'm not sure to understand the question I'm sorry, but I guess this is what you mean ? 
<p><asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" CellSpacing="12" 
                onselectedindexchanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
        </asp:CheckBoxList></p>

Comment: Nikhil : 
  Error 1 Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox'

Wow this is very strange, I don't understand what I'm facing with :(

Franky : Yep, this is what I tried to do with my CheckBox.Items[j].Selected but it didn't work :/

Comment: In MSDN Example (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx) they have also used Selected property for CheckBoxList.

Comment: This is just a shot in the dark, but are the property declarations case sensitive? So are you actually sure that the method is called? If not, then change `onselectedindexchanged` to `OnSelectedIndexChanged`.

Comment: I'm using visual studio so I can call methods with a GUI which automatically do it for me, but I'll try to change it aynyway ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected == true)
            {
                //Response.Write(item.Value);
                LabelTest.Text = item.Value;
            }
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding check box list items in page load then,
in page load:

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // load only fist time 
        LaodCheckBoxList();
    }
}
```

Since you enable autopostback true for checkboxlist it will postback and recreate all list items, you will lost selection state.

Comment: Thanks, but I've got the same issue as when I use ".Checked" : "blah blah doesn't not contain a definition for "GetItemCheckState" " :(

Comment: I just had this exact thought, but didn't see the answer down here :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know your code should work.
Try to change the for loop with a foreach

```
foreach (ListItem itm in CheckBoxList1.Items)
{             
    if (itm.Selected == true)             
    {                 
         TextBoxTest.Text = itm.Text;                 
         LabelTest.Text = itm.Value;             
    }         
}
```

Comment: I tried with a foreach but not the way you did it, I'm giving a try, thanks ! :)